# How to change UIDesign based on Internationalization?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, internationalization

I want to develop app for India and French. I am doing Localization for languages, but i want

to change the theme colours and images based on location i.e.; Internationalization.

How can achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Check out this link. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I implemented it, but i am asking for Internationalization to change Theme colours etc. based on country.

Comment: Yes, we can achieve based on Geolocation, Timezone etc.